# Create a generic List Wrapper to pass data between activities

Tags: java, android, generics, arraylist

i am building an app in which i have to pass data between activities. Data are `ArrayList` of custom `Object`. For this reason every model has to implement `Serializable` and then i have to create a `Wrapper` to pass the data.

I have something like this:

```
public class DummyJSONModelWrapper implements Serializable{

    private List<DummyJSONModel> dummyJSONModel;

    public DummyJSONModelWrapper(List<DummyJSONModel> dummyJSONModel) {
        this.dummyJSONModel = dummyJSONModel;
    }

    public List<DummyJSONModel> getDummyJSONModel() {
        return dummyJSONModel;
    }
}
```

my question is how to make the List that i pass into the constructor to be generic and also the getter to return generic list?

So i want to have something like:

```
public class DummyJSONModelWrapper implements Serializable{

    private List<T> dummyJSONModel;

    public DummyJSONModelWrapper(List<T> dummyJSONModel) {
        this.dummyJSONModel = dummyJSONModel;
    }

    public List<T> getDummyJSONModel() {
        return dummyJSONModel;
    }
}
```

but it does not work like this. What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare the Generic at the class level, like so:

```
public class DummyJSONModelWrapper<T extends DummyJSONModel> implements Serializable{

    private List<T> dummyJSONModel;

    public DummyJSONModelWrapper(List<T> dummyJSONModel) {
        this.dummyJSONModel = dummyJSONModel;
    }

    public List<T> getDummyJSONModel() {
        return dummyJSONModel;
    }
}
```

Refer to the documentation from Oracle [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

Comment: but i do not want to have something like DummyJSONModelWrapper<List>

Comment: I've updated the answer. You can now only use `DummyJSONModel` or its subclasses in your Wrapper. Does that help?

Comment: no i still have to use the DummyJSONModel... i want to use different models. it works but contains me to use the specific model

Comment: do all these models have a super class ?

Comment: no they dont...its just models for mapping json objects from http webservices

Comment: Then it is difficult to contain the Generic types. If you can refactor your Model classes to inherit from one type, then it would be possible to use this. Otherwise, you will have to use `public class DummyJSONModelWrapper<T> implements Serializable{`

Comment: you mean like build an abstract model to act like a superclass and each model should extend it and then i can do it the way you suggest right?

Comment: if you take out the  extends DummyJSONModel part it works perfect. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131159/discussion-between-patriarch-and-anacron).